# IIS ARR: disable or overwrite appended "X-Original-URL" HTTP header from forwarded requests

Tags: tomcat, iis, http-headers, url-rewrite-module, arr

We have an issue when IIS forwards large search request URLs (via ARR URL Rewrite) to a search API (with Solr in the backend) that is running on Tomcat, and Tomcat immediately rejects the request with a 400 - Bad Request error.

Full Tomcat response:

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Date: Thu, 12 Sep 2019 00:17:39 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close

The size/length of the URL is not the issue, but it's because IIS is including the original URL in the X-Original-URL header when forwarding the request to Tomcat, and it's not even the length of the URL in that header, but part of the contents of one of the query string parameters in the X-Original-URL header that is causing Tomcat to reject the request.

I've tried adding the maxHttpHeaderSize attribute to the connector in the config XML for Tomcat as:

<Connector port="9090" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" maxHttpHeaderSize="65536" redirectPort="9490" />

But increasing the max header size has had no effect.

I've verified that IIS/ARR has not decoded/re-encoded (or has otherwise modified the URL) in the X-Original-URL header by capturing the requests from IIS by proxying them through Fiddler and examining the forwarded requests.

With the IIS forwarded requests being proxied through Fiddler, I can remove the X-Original-URL from the request (via a custom Fiddler rule script) and then Tomcat accepts the request and processes it and the response gets forwarded back through IIS without issue.

We've managed to isolate the content of a query string parameter ("fq" specifying a search on the indexed "path" facet field in Solr) as being the possible culprit, because if we shorten the path value in that parameter by removing the last portion of the path, then the request does not get rejected. Unfortunately, trimming the path is not an option, as it is used as part of the search query in order to return search results that are contained within a specific path.

The following is an example (sorry about the length) of a path value that is causing the 400 error (when included as part of the X-Original-URL header):

> fq=path%3A(%22%5C%22TestOTIF%5C%22%5C-H4sIAAAAAAAAAKtWKlGyMtJRSlayUnIvyi8tUAhJTc7Iy8%5C%2FJT69U0lEqVrKKrlbKA0qGpBaX%5C%2BId4ugEFS5G5tbG1AATZhNNEAAAA%3B%5C%22Documents%5C%22%5C-H4sIAAAAAAAAAKtWKlGyMtJRSlayUnIvyi8tUAhJTc7Iy8%5C%2FJT69U0lEqVrKKrlbKA0qGpBaX%5C%2BId4ugEFS5G5tbE6SjlKVhBFLvnJpbmpeSXFUFXBGYlFqSkKCOHaWgCTIarwcQAAAA%3D%3D%3B%5C%22Luisa%5C%22%5C-H4sIAAAAAAAAAKtWKlGyMtJRSlayUnIvyi8tUAhJTc7Iy8%5C%2FJT69U0lEqVrKKrlbKA0qGpBaX%5C%2BId4ugEFS5G5tbE6SjlKVhBFLvnJpbmpeSXFUFXBGYlFqSkKCOFaHaU0uJE%5C%2BpZnFiUADagGOHHHLhQAAAA%3D%3D%3B%5C%22Council%5C%22%5C-H4sIAAAAAAAAAKtWKlGyMtJRSlayUnIvyi8tUAhJTc7Iy8%5C%2FJT69U0lEqVrKKrlbKA0qGpBaX%5C%2BId4ugEFS5G5tbE6SjlKVhBFLvnJpbmpeSXFUFXBGYlFqSkKCOFaHaU0uJE%5C%2BpZnFiUAhCM85vzQvOTMHaGAtADfvIOmVAAAA%3B%5C%22Meetings%5C%22%5C-H4sIAAAAAAAAAE2MvQrCMBRGX6V8c6aOWRWLoDiYTTqUeG0D8V5pcgcpeXcDlep4zvezIMO2Bh4W3Sz6ahz5iSXK%5C%2BIZBgr0t4Bo6Svnijocq9R9LbxBh19JevD6Jc%5C%2Fq2rtMw07356WLw2C5PGtJQ1Uo7UfYhbnwmyoHHuunLBzthuwemAAAA%3B%5C%22EC_161017_ECOE%5C%22%5C-H4sIAAAAAAAAAE2NwQoCIQBEf2WZs4fsUODVLIJiD3mLWBazXcE0Vj3E4r8nbFjH92aYmRHB1gQKDIfJp1cjtRqdt354gyCAXWe4EkodYiuP%5C%2ByLTP%5C%2BYbgQVbSjuv0lO7GL6ty9hP%5C%2Bt78dCZ41MlTMqEvaiHuk1PGVj5rHY0bQhWCd3RDV3TbCd6Kcpw%5C%2Fq6GCkr0AAAA%3D%3B%5C%22LP%5C%22%5C-H4sIAAAAAAAAAE2OQQvCIACF%5C%2F8p4Zw%5C%2BtQ4FXswgWC%5C%2FIWMYbZJpjG1EMM%5C%2F3vCwjp%5C%2B33s83owAuiaQoDhMLr4qoeRonXHDGwQe9DrD5lAoH1px3GcZ%5C%2FzHdCAzoUto5GZ%5C%2FKBv9tXcZ%5C%2BUvfqpxPBo0w2Ufs%5C%2Bq4WYi1ZqU%5C%2FikVNB28EVw1tWbelVvO85aXnRzzh%5C%2FSB6kO1JTIAAAA%3B%5C%22Revised+FEED+Phase+2+Docs+and+additional+docs+%5C-+not+to+print%5C%22%5C-H4sIAAAAAAAAAE2PwQrCMAyGXyXkPMF5UOh1VhGUDd1NREpbt8JMZW0FGXt3O5TqLd%5C%2BXn%5C%2FxkQI9skaFEhtvehgfUWrZkO9u8MEOH7DwgxWWtnS%5C%2Fr3SbK8I%5C%2FjJcMO2Se0tjLcNXn3TZ1a0WsFPz1meEsn98E4EdWHChtImi7xQWtvqHFJ8OKaL%5C%2FN5vrryouRJ76s0HvXTuNi34XwNVSuchsVU7kCQAqGU8caS6EBNbgZkPXgLj96Qj4%5C%2BMb0LvykANAQAA%3B%5C%22Control+Systems+and+Instrumentation%5C%22%5C-H4sIAAAAAAAAAE2PQWvDMAyF%5C%2F4rQOYWlhw5yTd1R6GhpcxujmNhrDK5cLHlQSv77nGV4vel9kp70HijYLCvsscG3GNINOtsPFHy43LFCxubjgZSbnWXZd9tNhulZjp8VemzmoXXo09WS8N%5C%2FUadDRGvjHY4VfxXKXHOuMZtWGRL3zRb9bK44uXIBqz%5C%2FWqfqlfz6rdq4J3h1Ie7bfjfG%5C%2Bj1BoOg2YLy%5C%2Bk4gyYD2hgnLpD2YCa2AAoCEuAWHcnTHyQxeDjdWex1Xt0SS%5C%2FyNoCeHHHr8AUaYBdM5AQAA%3B%5C%22Cause+and+Effect+Diagram%5C%22%5C-H4sIAAAAAAAAAE2QwWrDMBBEf2XZswt1Din4aislkJLQ%5C%2BFZKELJsC%5C%2BRVkFaFEPzvleui5KZ5O5pZ6Y6M1aZAhRW%5C%2Bexev0Go1krNuuGGBAauvO1Iatjrwsd3vEozPcv4u0GK1mhqn4qSJw7%5C%2FrPEqvO3jgucA%5C%2BRx6iCTKhVdUukjI26w%5C%2Bt2dAQMhD1pdyWr%5C%2BXbRdRHkfHhlI%5C%2Bf%5C%2BseE1LcTooHTKIOGzVIeQFIHsusMG0fSQrewFyDHwA6u3hA%5C%2F7UHsnYXzLbCe1qt7Cuz%5C%2FniCXhIdXxtSxOETfa8XQGDl4OaVfmX8BphIoiFoBAAA%3D%22)

The above encoded query string value contains forward slashes, escaped quotes (like \", but encoded as %5C%22), unique path folder IDs, and other stuff.

The above decoded:

```
fq=path:("\"TestOTIF\"\-H4sIAAAAAAAAAKtWKlGyMtJRSlayUnIvyi8tUAhJTc7Iy8\/JT69U0lEqVrKKrlbKA0qGpBaX\+Id4ugEFS5G5tbG1AATZhNNEAAAA;\"Documents\"\-H4sIAAAAAAAAAKtWKlGyMtJRSlayUnIvyi8tUAhJTc7Iy8\/JT69U0lEqVrKKrlbKA0qGpBaX\+Id4ugEFS5G5tbE6SjlKVhBFLvnJpbmpeSXFUFXBGYlFqSkKCOHaWgCTIarwcQAAAA==;\"Luisa\"\-H4sIAAAAAAAAAKtWKlGyMtJRSlayUnIvyi8tUAhJTc7Iy8\/JT69U0lEqVrKKrlbKA0qGpBaX\+Id4ugEFS5G5tbE6SjlKVhBFLvnJpbmpeSXFUFXBGYlFqSkKCOFaHaU0uJE\+pZnFiUADagGOHHHLhQAAAA==;\"Council\"\-H4sIAAAAAAAAAKtWKlGyMtJRSlayUnIvyi8tUAhJTc7Iy8\/JT69U0lEqVrKKrlbKA0qGpBaX\+Id4ugEFS5G5tbE6SjlKVhBFLvnJpbmpeSXFUFXBGYlFqSkKCOFaHaU0uJE\+pZnFiUAhCM85vzQvOTMHaGAtADfvIOmVAAAA;\"Meetings\"\-H4sIAAAAAAAAAE2MvQrCMBRGX6V8c6aOWRWLoDiYTTqUeG0D8V5pcgcpeXcDlep4zvezIMO2Bh4W3Sz6ahz5iSXK\+IZBgr0t4Bo6Svnijocq9R9LbxBh19JevD6Jc\/q2rtMw07356WLw2C5PGtJQ1Uo7UfYhbnwmyoHHuunLBzthuwemAAAA;\"EC_161017_ECOE\"\-H4sIAAAAAAAAAE2NwQoCIQBEf2WZs4fsUODVLIJiD3mLWBazXcE0Vj3E4r8nbFjH92aYmRHB1gQKDIfJp1cjtRqdt354gyCAXWe4EkodYiuP\+yLTP\+YbgQVbSjuv0lO7GL6ty9hP\+t78dCZ41MlTMqEvaiHuk1PGVj5rHY0bQhWCd3RDV3TbCd6Kcpw\/q6GCkr0AAAA=;\"LP\"\-H4sIAAAAAAAAAE2OQQvCIACF\/8p4Zw\+tQ4FXswgWC\/IWMYbZJpjG1EMM\/3vCwjp\+33s83owAuiaQoDhMLr4qoeRonXHDGwQe9DrD5lAoH1px3GcZ\/zHdCAzoUto5GZ\/KBv9tXcZ\+UvfqpxPBo0w2Ufs\+q4WYi1ZqU\/ikVNB28EVw1tWbelVvO85aXnRzzh\/SB6kO1JTIAAAA;\"Revised+FEED+Phase+2+Docs+and+additional+docs+\-+not+to+print\"\-H4sIAAAAAAAAAE2PwQrCMAyGXyXkPMF5UOh1VhGUDd1NREpbt8JMZW0FGXt3O5TqLd\+Xn\/xkQI9skaFEhtvehgfUWrZkO9u8MEOH7DwgxWWtnS\/r3SbK8I\/jJcMO2Se0tjLcNXn3TZ1a0WsFPz1meEsn98E4EdWHChtImi7xQWtvqHFJ8OKaL\/N5vrryouRJ76s0HvXTuNi34XwNVSuchsVU7kCQAqGU8caS6EBNbgZkPXgLj96Qj4\+Mb0LvykANAQAA;\"Control+Systems+and+Instrumentation\"\-H4sIAAAAAAAAAE2PQWvDMAyF\/4rQOYWlhw5yTd1R6GhpcxujmNhrDK5cLHlQSv77nGV4vel9kp70HijYLCvsscG3GNINOtsPFHy43LFCxubjgZSbnWXZd9tNhulZjp8VemzmoXXo09WS8N\/UadDRGvjHY4VfxXKXHOuMZtWGRL3zRb9bK44uXIBqz\/Wqfqlfz6rdq4J3h1Ie7bfjfG\+j1BoOg2YLy\+k4gyYD2hgnLpD2YCa2AAoCEuAWHcnTHyQxeDjdWex1Xt0SS\/yNoCeHHHr8AUaYBdM5AQAA;\"Cause+and+Effect+Diagram\"\-H4sIAAAAAAAAAE2QwWrDMBBEf2XZswt1Din4aislkJLQ\+FZKELJsC\+RVkFaFEPzvleui5KZ5O5pZ6Y6M1aZAhRW\+exev0Go1krNuuGGBAauvO1Iatjrwsd3vEozPcv4u0GK1mhqn4qSJw7\/rPEqvO3jgucA\+Rx6iCTKhVdUukjI26w\+t2dAQMhD1pdyWr\+XbRdRHkfHhlI\+f\+seE1LcTooHTKIOGzVIeQFIHsusMG0fSQrewFyDHwA6u3hA\/7UHsnYXzLbCe1qt7Cuz\/niCXhIdXxtSxOETfa8XQGDl4OaVfmX8BphIoiFoBAAA=")
```

My questions are:

1. Would any of the encoded information above be rejected by Tomcat for some reason (besides length) when it's included as a value in a HTTP header, or more specifically, when included in the X-Original-URL header?
2. I've tried to rewrite the HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL server variable in IIS URL Rewrite, but it doesn't work because IIS appends that header AFTER it has processed the rewrite rules. Is there any other way to possibly disable the inclusion of that specific header in IIS or ARR? Or at least to be able to overwrite/rewrite the value in that header?
3. For Tomcat, I've reviewed all of the possible config settings that may relate to request and/or header sizes/lengths, and didn't find anything beyond "maxHttpHeaderSize" that may have any effect on preventing the request rejection. Is there possibly some other setting that can be changed that would allow Tomcat to accept the requests?

Sorry about the long post here! :)

Any additional information or advice, or possible solutions, about this issue is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: try to add the iis url rewrite rule on the left-hand pane, select "View Server Variables...".  If you don't see HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL listed, select "Add..." and add the server variable.  Then you can go back and use it in your rule. and create rule to replace the value.

Comment: @Janvi: thanks for the comment, but I've already tried that. I've tried replacing the server variable via the rewrite rule and an outbound rule, but neither works because IIS appends the X-Original-URL header after the rules have been evaluated, even when I've set the value for that header.

Comment: @Janvi: And I did add that server variable (And all possible variations) via the "View Server Variables" section. Have you been able to successfully rewrite the X-Original-URL header via an IIS URL Rewrite or Outbound rule for forwarded requests?

Comment: you could try to use a Load balancer, for example, Microsoft Load Balancer or F5 [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/network-load-balancing.).by using NLB you can modify the URL and then redirect that URL to the apache.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to turn off the X-Original-URL in the header,

At the Server Level off IIS if you go to the Configuration Editor, then system.webServer/proxy setting.  Set the StealthMode to TRUE and it will stop sending the X-ORIGINAL-URL in the header.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies!

We found the issue - there was another Tomcat server in a proxy chain that needed to have the maxHttpHeaderSize config setting increased. Once that was set, we have no more 400 error. Yay!